# Excel formula - is it possible to return a value adjacent to a list of values, depending if that list of values matches another list?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, macros

In Sheet 1, I have a list of document numbers (alphanumeric) in Column A, which have a corresponding title listed in Column B.

I need to compare another list of document numbers (alphanumeric), (lets say in Sheet 2) with (Column A Sheet 1), and if they match, returns the corresponding title value found in Sheet 1 Column B.

For the blank Column B data, = I need to return a value here that compares column A (Sheet 2) to column A (Sheet 1), and if it matches, returns the value from the cell adjacent to column A (Sheet 1).

I hope that makes sense. Is it possible? Could anyone give me a formula or macro I could edit that would achieve this?

Comment: I'm not exactly understanding your examples.  Can you edit your question to clarify how your data is arranged in columns and rows.

Comment: This sounds like a trivial application of `VLOOKUP`.  Please research that (Excel has pretty good built-in help) and let us know if you have a specific problem with getting it to work.

Answer (score 1):

```
=IF(OFFSET('Sheet 1'!$A$1,MATCH('Sheet 2'!A1,'Sheet 1'!$A:$A,0)-1,1)<>"",OFFSET('Sheet 1'!$A$1,MATCH('Sheet 2'!A1,'Sheet 1'!$A:$A,0)-1,1),OFFSET('Sheet 1'!$A$1,MATCH('Sheet 2'!A1,'Sheet 1'!$A:$A,0)-1,1))
```

What you requested for the unfound values is the same you requested for found values, if you really want to fiddle around with shifting based on position you will need this DIY vlookup.